東北地方で「だっけ」という表現
東北地方で「そうだっけ」とか「たのしかったっけ」の語尾の「だっけ」や「け」はどういう意味ですか。

Are you specifically asking for the usage of っけ in 東北 or just more generally?

asking just for the usage of っけ in 東北 district.

「そうだっけ」「たのしかったっけ」は標準語では疑問 ("is that so?") を表しますが、東北の一部の方言では「～んだよ」のような意味になるそうです。

昨日さぁ、急に雨降ってきてびっしょびしょに濡れたんだっけ〜
→ 昨日さぁ、急に雨降ってきてびっしょびしょに濡れたんだよね〜
(source)


昨日スーパー行ったんだっけ！
→ 昨日スーパーに行ったんだよ。
(source)

東北出身ではないので実際に聞いたことはありませんが…
